# display a calculation term in MATLAB

Tags: matlab

Once I have entered an expression like this

```
term = a*14*b^2*(1/3*a)^3;
```

I can easily display the result of the calculation of this term but how can I display the term again ?

Something like:

```
>> term

term = 

a*14*b^2*(1/3*a)^3;
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [inline](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/inline.html) or [anonymous](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_prog/anonymous-functions.html?s_tid=doc_12b) function instead. For example:

```
term = @(a,b) a*14*b^2*(1/3*a)^3;
```

then, say `a=3 ; b=4;`

```
term(a,b)
ans =
   672
```

and

```
term
    term = 
    @(a,b)a*14*b^2*(1/3*a)^3
```

or:

```
term = inline('a*14*b^2*(1/3*a)^3','a','b')

term =

 Inline function:
 term(a,b) = a*14*b^2*(1/3*a)^3

term(a,b)

ans =

   672
```

Alternatively, you can search the command history: first use MATLAB's Java internals to get the command history as a character array:

```
history = com.mathworks.mlservices.MLCommandHistoryServices.getSessionHistory;
historyText = char(history);
```

Then you can search `historyText`, using functions like [`strfind`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/strfind.html) or [`regexpi`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/regexpi.html). Or you can make a cell array of strings instead (one line per cell) with the function `cellstr`, since they can sometimes be easier to work with. (credit to @gnovice for sharing this method originally)

Answer (score 1):

The simple answer is: you can't.  The expression has already been evaluated.

You can press the "up" key in the command window to retrieve previous commands, though.

Comment: This is not quite accurate. That depends how `a` and `b` are defined. If they are symbolic variables, then it's possible.